# VLC hiding Ubuntu left panel (Unity Launcher)

Tags: 20.04, unity, launcher, vlc

Recenty, when I played a video in VLC media player 3.0.9.2, I is hiding the Ubuntu left panel (Unity Launcher). This issue was not there initially (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS).

But When I enable `Always on Top`, It goes to normal, but if I enable `Always on Top` from settings permanently, it is again having the issue, and when I disable it from `View`, it goes back to normal.

[image]
[image]